# How to iterate a private collection member in a Java class?

Tags: java, private, public

So here's this class which has a field, let's say
`Stack<Integer> changed_vertices` and it's *private* and *iterable*. If it were a primitive type variable, I would write a getter to get the value from other classes. But I need to iterate this stack from the outside (from other classes).

What kind of 'getter' can I implement for iterating this stack? Due to some reasons I can't change it from *private* to *public*.

Thanks.

Comment: A copy of the stack? A reference to its iterator? Where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I'm a Java noob ) No, I wouldn't want to copy this stack as it will take O(n) time. What can I do? Return the reference to the stack and iterate it using this reference? Is that a good programming style?

Comment: If you want clients to have access to the `Stack` and all its operations, return a `Stack`. If you want them to only be able to retrieve an iterator, return an `Iterable`. If you want them to only have access to the current iterator, return an `Iterator`.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options.

Simply return the stack:

```
public Stack<Integer> getChangedVertices()
{
    return changed_vertices;
}
```

Return the stack as unmodifiable List:

```
public List<Integer> getChangedVertices()
{
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(changed_vertices);
}
```

Return an iterator:

```
public Iterator<Integer> getChangedVertices()
{
    return changed_vertices.iterator();
}
```

Accept a consumer, and push the stack content into the consumer

```
public void consumeChangedVertices(Consumer<Integer> action)
{
    changed_vertices.stream().forEach(action);
}
```

etc.

It all depends on what the caller needs to do and/or should be allowed to do with the stack.

Comment: Of all the options the first one seems the best as it gives more freedom. Thanks a lot!